# Produce sentence with letters alternating in case

Tags: java

I realize a program in java that allows to generate this succession with a chain of the following way:

Input:

Hello World

good vibes

chain with succession:

hElLo wOrLd

gOoD vIbEs

Try to do it transforming the String input to an array type string with a split, then with an if, go checking the even positions, and transforming the letter that is in that lowercase position, and with the odd positions, the same, only that converting to capital letters ... The problem is that the array also saves the blanks, which causes a lag in the sequence, and I can not remove it, since I must show the text with the inputtext format, What can I do to fulfill the succession, without altering the spaces and line breaks that it has?

program give me:

hElLo wOrLd

GoOd vIbEs

code:

```
public String cambiar(String cadena1)
{
cambiar= cadena1.split("");

for(int i=0; i<cambiar.length; i++)
{
    if(i%2==0)
    {
        cambiar[i]=cambiar[i].toLowerCase();
    }
    else
    {
        cambiar[i]=cambiar[i].toUpperCase();
    }
}
 for(int i=0; i<cambiar.length; i++)
{
    textocambiado+=cambiar[i];

}

return textocambiado;
   }
```

NOTE: I am not allowed to use arraylist

The problem: https://drive.google.com/open?id=15VOlyhGtyvZ_0vcFype2o1sjiKkj7Hzn

Comment: Does your code work?

Comment: What is the input when the method is called, one line or multiple lines?

Comment: All the text of another textarea, and well there, the format can be only one line, or several lines, as the user decides to write

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, you just need to skip incrementing the counter for non-letters.

Another two performance improvements you could consider:

- Using a `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating to a string
- Using a `boolean` that you flip around instead of checking if the counter `i` is odd or even:

```
public String cambiar(String input) {
    boolean isLower = true;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
        char ch = input.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
            if (isLower) {
                result.append(Character.toLowerCase(ch));
            } else {
                result.append(Character.toUpperCase(ch));
            }
            isLower = !isLower;
        } else {
            result.append(ch);
        }
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Mark error in this lines:  "StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(input.size());" y "toLower = !toLower;"

Comment: @AxwellDuarte writing code without checking it in an IDE :-) edited and fixed, try now.

Comment: Is well, but a have a error with the sucesion when exist a jump line, the sucesion change and only work with the first line

Comment: The program give me: "hElLo WoRd 
GoOd ViBeS " and not "hElLo WoRd 
GoOd ViBeS"

Comment: I gonna put a capture to show this problem better, please look out

Comment: allrigth, i do it, but now, how i can fix this?